# JOMSOCIAL: An error at New User Registration Progress bar

Tags: php, joomla

During user Registration progress bar is set to 150% in step 3 and to 134% in step 4. Here is the code from `progressbar.php`:

```
<?php
class CProgressbarHelper{

    static public function getHTML( $max=100, $currval=0, $barclass='outerpgbar', $barfillclass='innerpgbar'){

        if(!is_numeric($max) || !is_numeric($currval) || $max < 0 || $currval < 0)
        return '<div>Progress bar cannot be generated properly</div>';

        $width = intval(($currval/$max) * 100) ;
        $barclass = (!empty($barclass))
                    ? 'class="'.$barclass.'"'
                    : 'style="background-color:white; height:.8em; border :1px solid #D0D0D0; margin-bottom:10px; padding:1px; "' ;

        $barfillclass = (!empty($barfillclass))
                    ? 'class="'.$barfillclass.'" style="width:'.$width.'%;"'
                    : 'style="width:'.$width.'%; height: 100%; background-color:blue; position:relative;"' ;

        //class progressbarfill : inside of the progress bar
        $html = '<div '.$barclass.' >'.
                    '<div '.$barfillclass.'></div>'.
                '</div>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

I have also tried an answer to such an issue at another blog as to change the line 1055 of `/administrator/components/com_community/installer.helper.php` from

```
$html .='<div class="outerpg"><div class="innerpgbar" style="width:'.$percentage.'%;"> '. $percentage .'%</div></div>';
```

to

```
$html .='<div class="outerpg"><div class="innerpgbar" style="width:'.($percentage/2).'%;"> '. $(percentage/2) .'%</div></div>';
```

But it is still not working properly. In fact, it has cut the progress bar in half on the first user registration page.

I can't show the image here clearly, but you can understand it by registering at Jomsocial>>Demo. In fact, you won't see the error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which called this function passed a value for `$currval` which is higher than `$max`. Something like `getHTML(100, 154)` (this will give you 154% as result).

You may add the following line:

```
if ($currval > $max) $currval = $max;
```

(before the `$width = intval(($currval/$max) * 100);` line)

This way, you avoid having percentage higher than 100%.